# How to handle map<dynamic> null object when api is called

Tags: android, dart, flutter

How can I manage server response if `status` is either than `200`.

```
@JsonSerializable(nullable: false)
class LoginResponse {
  final String error;
  final int status;
  final List<User> userList;
  LoginResponse({this.error, this.status, this.userList});

  factory LoginResponse.fromJson(Map repJson){

List<dynamic> userListResp=repJson['userData'];
List<User> userList=userListResp.map((e)=>User.fromUser(e)).toList();
int s=repJson['status'];
   if(s==200){
     return LoginResponse(error:repJson['error'],status: repJson['status'],userList:userList);
   } else{
     return LoginResponse(error:repJson['error'],status: repJson['status']);
   }}}

  class User{
  String cust_id;
  String cust_name;
  String cust_email;
  String cust_mob;

  User({this.cust_id,this.cust_name,this.cust_email,this.cust_mob});
  factory User.fromUser(Map userJson){
    return User(cust_id: userJson['cust_id'],cust_name: userJson['cust_name'],
        cust_email: userJson['cust_email'],cust_mob: userJson['cust_mob']);
  }
}
```

server response when an error is occur

```
{"error":"1","status":201,"message":"Entered email id already exist in our records"}
```

server response on success

```
  {
"error":"0",
"status":200,
"userData":[
 {
    "cust_id":"87",
    "cust_name":"kio",
    "cust_email":"kio1@kio.com",
    "cust_gend":null,
    "cust_dob":null,
    "cust_mob":"098998899889588",
    "cust_pass":"e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e",
    "cust_age":null,
    "device_type":"android",
    "device_token":"eNWqzDwxqsQ:APA91bF-uK1MI11D3SgHGSw7Omv1imjDrPKBBCrN9JgmyJppHsNVeG5l56EkCCd5ZMaxL_ehQzVhtoEj0fTNB55wYGJt5BqYVvwfAb7HrBqwb_21M6VFPuF6LQINkvE1offQgZYweROO",
    "status":"0",
    "createAt":"2019-01-31 18:45:19",
    "updatedAt":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "login_type":"",
    "login_id":null,
    "is_guest":"0",
    "auth_token":"",
    "forgot_token":null
 }]
}
```

How can I manage when user data is not present or null, I tried to manage when the `status code is 201` but still showing

> NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your code move the userList mapping inside the if block. This way you will parse the response only of the status code is 200.

```
int s=repJson['status'];
if (s==200) {
  List<dynamic> userListResp=repJson['userData'];
  List<User> userList=userListResp.map((e)=>User.fromUser(e)).toList();
  return LoginResponse(error:repJson['error'], status:repJson['status'], userList:userList);
} else {
  return LoginResponse(error:repJson['error'], status:repJson['status']);
}
```

However, you might not want to handle errors in your model. It is better to check for error after you performed the request and then decide if you want to parse the response.

Something like this will be easier to handle and won't pollute your model object:

```
final response = await client.get(requestUrl);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
  final loginResponse = LoginResponse.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));

  // ...
} else {
  // If that call was not successful, throw an error or parse the error object.
  throw Exception('Failed to login');

  // ...
}
```

Comment: `response.statusCode == 200` it will always show 200 because there is no server error until I get the response from the server.

Comment: Ok, then the first approach should fix your problem.

Comment: I updated the answer, userListResp should be created before the mapping happens. Does it still show an error and if so where it fails?